# .htaccess - conditionaly redirect subfolders

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to implement followin in .htaccess file:

I have "dictionary", which tells me, which subfolder should be redirected where, i.e.

```
domain1.com/a -> domain2.com/x
domain1.com/b -> domain2.com/y
```

and everything else should be redirected to

```
domain2.com/z
```

That should be simple enough, but I can not figure it out.

My code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:https]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:http]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www\.)?domain1.com/a$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  %{ENV:proto}://domain2.com/x [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www\.)?domain1.com/b$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  %{ENV:proto}://domain2.com/y [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www\.)?domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  %{ENV:proto}://domain2.com/z [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `%{HTTP_HOST}` only matches domain not request uri.

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:https]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:http]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^a/?$  %{ENV:proto}://domain2.com/x [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^b/?$  %{ENV:proto}://domain2.com/y [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:proto}://domain2.com/z [L,NC,R=301]
```